# append a rearrange json.values() and if empty then put it as empty list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I wish to check the total "id" appeared( 12 "id" in this case) and then create an empty list to append the "item_task" according to "item_id" in sequence order.

Example, 1:play, 2:give, 3:give, 4:check.......12:nice (Completed)

Since "item_id" for number 6 is not listed, then I would like to assign an empty list to it. "item_id" ---> 6:[].... I would like it to automatically check which "item_id" does not include inside the json. In this example I give 6 but sometimes 5 or 12 is not inside. Is there a way to do so?

Below is my json file.

json =

```
[ {
  "testing" : [ {
    "example" : {
    },
    "get" : [ {
      "id" : "0",
      "item" : [ {
        "get_id" : "1",
        "item_task" : "play"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : "1",
      "item" : [ ],
    } ]
  }, {
    "example" : {

    },
    "get" : [ {
      "id" : "2",
      "item" : [ ],
    } ]
  }, {
    "example" : {

      } ]
    },
    "get" : [ {
      "id" : "3",
      "item" : [ {
        "item_id" : "2",
        "item_task" : "give"
      } ],
    } ]
  }, {
    "example" : {

    },
    "get" : [ {
      "id" : "4",
      "item" : [ {
        "item_id" : "5",
        "item_task" : "play"
      } ],
    }, {
      "id" : "5"
    } ]
  }, {
    "example" : {

    },
    "get" : [ {
      "id" : "6",
      "item" : [ {
        "item_id" : "0",
        "item_task" : "let"
      }, {
        "item_id" : "3",
        "item_task" : "give"
      }, {
        "item_id" : "4",
        "item_task" : "check"
      }, {
        "item_id" : "7",
        "item_task" : "nice"
      }, {
        "item_id" : "8",
        "item_task" : "nice"
      }, {
        "item_id" : "9",
        "item_task" : "do"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : "7",
    }, {
      "id" : "8",
    }, {
      "id" : "9"
    } ]
  }, {
    "example" : {

    },
    "get" : [ {
      "id" : "10",
      "item" : [ {
        "item_id" : "11",
        "item_task" : "nice"
      }, {
        "item_id" : "12",
        "item_task" : "nice"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : "11",
    }, {
      "id" : "12"
    } ]
  } ]
} ]
```

My code to (1) calculate the number of 'id'. (2) Find the difference between 'id' and 'item_id' (3) Add an empty list to whichever 'item_id' not in the json file.

```
count = 0
for test in u[0]['testing']:
    for value in test["get"]:
        if "id" in valu:
            count += 1


value = []
for test in u[0]["testing"]:
    for value in test["get"]:
        if 'item' in value:
            for u in value["item"]:
                for i in range(count):
                    if str(i) not in u["item_id"]:
                        print(str(i))
```

However I did not get the 'item_id' that is not inside the json file. Can you help me pls

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: test = []
new = []

count = 0
for test in u[0]['testing']:
    for value in test["get"]:
        if "id" in valu:
            count += 1

I use this to calculate the number of 'id' but I am stuck with how to compare the difference between the number of 'id' and number of 'item_id'. I am calculating this because I want to get the difference between these two and then add another 'item_id' with empty list [] according to the amount of difference. I have updated my post above with some example of my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not that far, but I had to fix your initial `u` because it contains syntax errors and a `"get_id"` key that should certainly read `"item_id"`.

What should be done?

In both loops, you should consistently add the items to appropriate container: a list for the ids and a dict for the item_tasks. And please **never reuse a variable name**!

```
for u in value["item"]:
```

is plain wrong because it overwrites your main structure that is named... **`u`**.

Code could be:

```
count = 0
ids = []
for test in u[0]['testing']:
    for value in test["get"]:
        if "id" in value:
            ids.append(value["id"])
            count += 1

task = {}
del tasks
for test in u[0]["testing"]:
    for value in test["get"]:
        if 'item' in value:
            for x in value["item"]:
                if x['item_id'] in ids:
                    task[x['item_id']] = x['item_task']
```

Ok you have separately the ids, and the tasks. You can then build an ordered dict with that:

```
import collections
resul = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in ids:
    resul[i] = task.get(i, [])

print(resul)
OrderedDict([('0', 'let'), ('1', 'play'), ('2', 'give'), ('3', 'give'), ('4', 'check'), ('5', 'play'), ('6', []), ('7', 'nice'), ('8', 'nice'), ('9', 'do'), ('10', []), ('11', 'nice'), ('12', 'nice')])
```

Because no task was given for 6 and 10.

Comment: Thank you sir. Have already completed but I will take this as reference, too.